# Reference to the activated program in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I am working with OpenGL and for some classes I wrote I would have to pass a shader, although the class is only used, when a shader is already active. Is there a way to get the currently active program from OpenGL, so a function like `glGetActiveProgram()`?

Comment: This is an OpenGL question or  a WebGL question? Those 2 tags are mutually exclusive so please pick one or the other . Since you wrote OpenGL 3 times and referenced an OpenGL function then I'm assuming this is an OpenGL question. OpenGL and WebGL are not the same. They have many differences, not the least of which is OpenGL is programmed in C and WebGL in JavaScript but there are also many API differences.

Comment: Why do you even write this on a answered question? I am working with OpenGL and WebGL of course not in the same project. My main target was OpenGL but since I also got an answer on how to do that in WebGL I added the WebGL tag, so that WebGL developers can also find it. Thats also why I didn't add a programming language

Comment: We do it because mixing the two APIs will lead to tears, bugs, and frustration since they are not the same. Advice for one will often lead to unexpected results for the other. Mixing them is as bad as asking a programming question and asking for both c++ and JavaScript answers. If you want two answers ask two questions.

Comment: Why do you even care so much? Nobody gets hurt except the feelings of perfectionists like you. I don't see any contradiction in asking the same question for two languages! Splitting the question up creates two duplicates with just different tags. You don't have to go to separate driving schools if you want to drive a Mercedes instead of a BMW. Cars from the brands are different, just like WebGL and OpenGL, but still share many features and are built on the same idea.

Comment: I care because I have to clean up the mess you cause. Someone confuses the two, thinks they're they same, goes and reads the docs for the other API then posts a question on S.O. "why doesn't this work". Reason: You looked at the wrong API docs/resources/S.O. question. You were led to believe they're the same, they aren't.

Comment: Nobody that knows WebGL or OpenGL could confuse the answer with OpenGL / WebGL, since the answer clearly states OpenGL and I asked for an WebGL version in a comment. Even if they completely missed the text and just saw the code they would know the language, since JS lacks the `GLint` type and also doesn't have accessible pointers. Just leave this question alone, it is answered since almost a day anyways

Comment: People that know WebGL and OpenGL aren't asking questions on S.O. As someone that's answered about 20% of all the questions on WebGL here I know this is a source of confusion for users. Please be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`glGetIntegerv()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml) with `GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM`:

```cpp
GLint prog = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &prog);
```

Standard "querying OpenGL state isn't guaranteed to be performant" disclaimer applies.

Comment: Thanks, that's working, do you know how I can use that in WebGL? There somehow is no `gl.getIntegerv`

Comment: @user11914177: [Looks](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.3) like `getParameter()` with `CURRENT_PROGRAM`.  Not super-familiar with the WebGL spec conventions so those names may or may not have  `gl`/`webgl`/`GL_` prefixes.